# Welche Präposition gehört zu "Exposition"?

Tags: usage, preposition

Wenn ich einem Stoff (z.B. einem Umweltgift) ausgesetzt bin, ist das dann eine Exposition *durch* diesen Stoff? Oder was nimmt man da?

Comment: Das klingt sehr merkwürdig. Nimm das Verb: *Man ist den Stoffen exponiert.* -  Wenn du den Satz so schreiben willst, würde ich zu *gegenüber* tendieren.

Comment: Ich hätte ergänzen sollen, dass es um einen Fachtext geht. *Eine kurzfristige Exposition ... X-Säure führt zu ...* -- so in der Richtung. Da wird es mit dem Verb schwierig. Aber *gegenüber* scheint in der Toxikologie tatsächlich sehr gebräuchlich zu sein, wie Google nahelegt. Das nehme ich, danke! (Kannst du eine Antwort daraus machen? Dann kann ich sie akzeptieren.)

Comment: Sehe gerade, dass Takkat auch *gegenüber* vorgeschlagen hat. Deshalb markiere ich seine Antwort. (Aber noch mal: danke.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unter **Exposition** versteht man in der Toxikologie die Einwirkung und Einwirkdauer eines gesundheitsschädlichen Schadstoffes auf den Menschen. Meist, und möglicherweise um eine nicht so genau definierte Präposition zu vermeiden, wird eine Komposition gebildet:

> - Schadstoffexposition
> - Asbestexposition
> - Quecksilberexposition

Wenn man aber unbedingt eine Präposition braucht, schlage ich zwei Alternativen vor, die meines Erachtens beide richtig sind:

> - Exposition **gegenüber** Asbest
> - Exposition **mit** Chlorkohlenwasserstoff

Die Präposititonen *"durch"*, *"für"* oder *"von"* sind wahrscheinlich nicht falsch, aber in diesem Kontext weniger gebräuchlich. Vermutlich wird *"durch"* wegen der folgenden Formulierung als richtig angesehen:

> Die Schädigung erfolgt **durch** Exposition gegenüber/mit Asbest.

Comment: Danke. Eine Komposition ist natürlich auch eine gute Möglichkeit. Für meinen Zweck ist *gegenüber* die beste Wahl, das in einem kleinen Googletest (Suchbegriffe: toxikologie "exposition gegenüber" bzw. "exposition mit") auch gebräuchlicher erscheint, im toxikologischen Kontext jedenfalls (207.000 vs. 25.000 Ergebnisse).

Comment: Bei Flüssigkeiten und Gasen darf man durchaus *in* sagen, das sagt auch der Lateiner so ("Hinausstellung ins Freie/in den Regen,..."). Das geht mit Feststoffen natürlich nicht ganz so gut....

Answer (score 5):

Das Verb ist exponieren und das funktioniert mit dem Dativ.

> Ich exponiere mich dem Wind.

Es ist also wie geben. Will man geben inklusive des Rezipienten substantivieren, kommt eine sehr windschiefe Konstruktion heraus.

> Das mir-Geben des Buches war sehr nett von dir.

Ergo … eigentlich ist eine solche Konstruktion mit Exposition nicht möglich. Alle angeführten Optionen sind grammatikalisch falsch, da sie nicht mit dem Verb funktionieren. Sprache lebt, und wenn eine solche Konstruktion gebraucht wird, wird sie sich durchsetzen. Offensichtlich herrscht aber noch kein Konsens und für mich klingt alles gleich schief.

Comment: Ich habe mir die Überlegung mit "aussetzen" und "Aussetzung" gemacht und bin zum selben Entschluss gekommen. Von diesem Vergleich ausgehend, war ich zu dem Entschluss gekommen, dass "gegenüber" die beste Möglichkeit ist, wenn man diese merkwürdige Konstruktion tatsächlich machen möchte.